# Different tools to graph memory usage in node.js apps?

Tags: debugging, memory, node.js

I'm working on a project that has a couple of persistent processes that run in node.js. As I'm adding to the project, I'd like to be able to start charting the memory usage of each process over time as part of my debugging process.

I'm aware this might not even specifically be a node.js question. My knowledge of the various tools to get this particular kind of job done is sparse and I need some direction.

My production environment is an Ubuntu 11.04 server instance, and my dev machine runs Snow Leopard.

What kinds of tools should I be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From inside of your node process, you can run

```
process.memoryUsage()
```

Then you can feed those three values into your data collection / graphing system.